# Blade Templating Engine doesn't yields the section

Tags: php, laravel, layout, yield, laravel-blade

Trying to **@yields** the **@section('content')** from **welcome.blade.php** view, but I am unable to get any result on the webpage.

**views/layouts/master.blade.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <p>Hello World!</p>
        @yield('content')
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**views/welcome.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.master')

    @section('content')
        This is content!
        @endsection
```

Displaying **Hello World!** on the webpage, but not yielding the content from the extended layout.

I have checked the code several times, but unable to find the solution. I have used this templating engine before, but it worked fine. Unfortunately, it doesn't making any sense this time.

Comment: Have a look at the page source of the displayed html page.

Comment: This is what in the Page Source. @linuxartisan
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <p>Hello World!</p>
            </div>

</body>
</html>

Comment: Where did the title _Laravel 5.2_ come from in the `<title>` tags? You don't seem to have it in `master.blade.php`.

Comment: When you say you have _removed it_, do you mean manually from the comment? Please update your question and add the actual html that you are getting. Please do not edit it yourself.

Comment: @linuxartisan When I posted the question, there was no title. But I added it later. Thats why it got displayed when I checked the page source. The problem is, @yeild() is not working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121899/discussion-between-linuxartisan-and-ahmed-qayyum).